# Evaluate Gauss-like Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Evaluate Integral

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ay^{2}-\frac{b}{y^2}}dy $$

Where a and b are real and positive.

This integral is eerily similar to the Gaussian integral

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}dx = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}$$

This is an integral I have come across as a step in a problem doing some homework for Advanced Statistics... Not sure where to begin.

Comment: From $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, the value is $~e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac\pi a}$

Comment: If that is true then the integral is $1/2$ that value since its symmetric around $y=0$.

Comment: In general, $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\exp\bigg(-ax^n-\dfrac b{x^n}\bigg)dx=\dfrac{2\cdot\sqrt[2n]{\dfrac ba}\cdot\text{BesselK}\bigg(\dfrac1n,\sqrt{2ab}\bigg)}n\quad$ See [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $u=ay-\frac by$, then $a^2y^2+\frac{b^2}{y^2}=2ab+u^2$. Furthermore, $y=\frac{u+\sqrt{u^2+4ab}}{2a}$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2y^2-\frac{b^2}{y^2}}\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\frac1{2ae^{2ab}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}(u+\sqrt{u^2+4ab})\\
&=\frac1{2ae^{2ab}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u
+\frac1{2ae^{2ab}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}\sqrt{u^2+4ab}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2ae^{2ab}}+0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: For $b=0$ you should recover the old result. Maybe $\sqrt{a}$ in the denominator? Edit: Sorry  see you use $a\to a^2$ and $b\to b^2$ compared to the original expr.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is taken from my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/766005/123277).
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{v=0}^\infty \exp\left(-av^2-\frac{b}{v^2}\right)\,dv&=\int_{v=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(v^2+\frac{b}{av^2}\right)\right)\,dv\\
&=\int_{v=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(v^2-2\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}+\frac{b}{av^2}+2\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)\right)\,dv\\
&=\int_{v=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(v-\frac{1}{v}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2-2\sqrt{ab}\right)\,dv\\
&=\exp(-2\sqrt{ab})\int_{v=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(v-\frac{1}{v}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2\right)\,dv\\
\end{align}
$$
The trick to solve the last integral is by setting
$$
I=\int_{v=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(v-\frac{1}{v}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2\right)\,dv.
$$
Let $t=-\frac{1}{v}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\;\rightarrow\;v=-\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\;\rightarrow\;dv=\frac{1}{t^2}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\,dt$, then
$$
I_t=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\int_{t=0}^\infty \frac{\exp\left(-a\left(-\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}+t\right)^2\right)}{t^2}\,dt.
$$
Let $t=v\;\rightarrow\;dt=dv$, then
$$
I_t=\int_{t=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2\right)\,dt.
$$
Adding the two $I_t$s yields
$$
2I=I_t+I_t=\int_{t=0}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)\exp\left(-a\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2\right)\,dt.
$$
Let $s=t-\frac{1}{t}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\;\rightarrow\;ds=\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)dt$ and for $0<t<\infty$ is corresponding to $-\infty<s<\infty$, then
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{s=-\infty}^\infty e^{-as^2}\,ds=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}.
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{v=0}^\infty \exp\left(-av^2-\frac{b}{v^2}\right)\,dv&=\exp(-2\sqrt{ab})\int_{v=0}^\infty \exp\left(-a\left(v-\frac{1}{v}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\right)^2\right)\,dv\\
&=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-ay^{2} - b/y^{2}}\,\dd y:\ {\large ?}.\qquad
     a, b > 0}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-ay^{2} - b/y^{2}}\,\dd y}
> \ =\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \exp\pars{-\root{ab}\bracks{\root{a \over b}y^{2} + \root{b \over a}y^{-2}}}
> \,\dd y}^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\quad\pars{a \over b}^{1/4}y \equiv \expo{\theta}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> \exp\pars{-\root{ab}\bracks{\expo{2\theta} + \expo{-2\theta}}}
> \pars{b \over a}^{1/4}\expo{\theta}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&=\pars{b \over a}^{1/4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> \exp\pars{-\root{ab}\bracks{2\cosh\pars{2\theta}}}
> \bracks{\cosh\pars{\theta} + \sinh\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> \\[1cm]&=2\pars{b \over a}^{1/4}\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \exp\pars{-2\root{ab}\bracks{2\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta} + 1}}
> \cosh\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta}^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\quad t \equiv \sinh\pars{\theta}}}
> \\[1cm]&=2\pars{b \over a}^{1/4}\exp\pars{-2\root{ab}}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-4\root{ab}t^{2}}\,\dd t
> \\[1cm]&=2\pars{b \over a}^{1/4}\exp\pars{-2\root{ab}}
> \bracks{{1 \over 2\pars{ab}^{1/4}}
> \ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-t^{2}}\,\dd t}^{\ds{\root{\pi} \over 2}}} 
> =\ \color{#66f}{\large\half\,\root{\pi \over a}\expo{-2\root{ab}}}
> \end{align}