# How to integrate this fourier transform?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I want to integrate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{itx}}{{1+x^2}} dx.$$ I don't see how substitution or integration by parts could help here. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: I happen to remember that it is $\pi e^{-|t|}$.

Comment: See my answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/766005/123277) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/766093/123277).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the complex function $f(z,t)=\frac{e^{itz}}{1+z^2}$ and consider the complex upper semicircle, from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$, the only pole in that region is a simple pole, $z=i$, so we can summarise our integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{itx}}{1+x^2}=2\pi iRes(f(z,t),z=i))$

Here $Res(f(z,t),z=i))=\lim_{z\to i}(z-i)f(z,t)=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)}=\frac{e^{-t}}{2i}$

Thus:

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{itx}}{1+x^2}=2\pi i\frac{e^{-t}}{2i}=\pi e^{-t}$

Comment: wow... why the downvote?

Comment: if there is a problem please say so...

Comment: it was not me...actually, I just upvoted yours...

Comment: @Lipschitz
:) it was a comment at the community, really if you downvote you should put some kind of reasoning, or suggestion for improvement

Comment: actually, you could also answer my question fully if you could answer my question in the comment to TheSparkThatThought's answer.

Comment: @Lipschitz, yes I was pondering this, but imagine, $a=10$ and $z=1$ (because $-a\le z\le a$) here the bound does not hold, so it may be a typo.

Comment: @Lipschitz, so we consider the semi circle, defined by $|z|=a$ for $a\gt 1$ then we have $|z|^2=|z^2|=|z^2+1-1|\le|z^2+1|+1$ therefore, $|z^2+1|\ge|z|^2-1=|a|^2-1=|a^2-1|$, so $\frac{1}{|z^2+1|}\le\frac{1}{|a^2-1|}$

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to do a contour integral? This specific problem is actually solved on Wikipedia's [page on this subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_integration#Example_.28II.29_.E2.80.93_Cauchy_distribution).