# Prove that: $e^{-\frac{|t|}{2}}= \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{e^{ixt}}{1+x^2} dx.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need help for prove that
$$e^{-\frac{|t|}{2}}= \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{e^{ixt}}{1+x^2} dx, \quad \forall t\in \mathbb R.$$
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you prove that the value of the integral is real? (Hint: apply $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$.)

Comment: this has been asked before

Comment: @qbert Can you link to the previous iteration? That makes it easier to vote to close.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/846961/321264.

Comment: The RHS ia actually $\pi e^{-|t|}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $t\geq 0$, examine 
$$
\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{e^{izt}}{1+z^2}\mathrm dz
$$
using the usual contour $\Gamma_R$ (semicircle union the real axis) in the upper half plane.

If $t<0$, examine 
$$
\int_{\Gamma_R'} \frac{e^{izt}}{1+z^2}\mathrm dz
$$
where now $\Gamma_R'$ is the contour $\Gamma_R$ reflected across the real axis.

This will insure that the contribution of the arc is 0 in either case.

Comment: "This has been asked before", you noted.  Then you answer anyway.

Comment: @amWhy I could not find the previous iteration and offered a hint on the chance that OP wants a hint, rather than a fully worked answer. If you feel strongly, I would be happy to delete it.