# Moment generating function of a cauchy distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Does the moment generating function of a Cauchy distribution given below exist? How do I show that the mean of the Cauchy does not exist? Please help. I am stuck on how to go about it.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx} \frac{1}{\pi(1+(x-\theta)^2)} \mathrm dx
$$

Comment: The MGF does not exist because this integral is not absolutely convergent. Same goes for the mean and any higher moments. See the theoretical answers in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36027/why-does-the-cauchy-distribution-have-no-mean) thread. Or by showing that the [mean does not exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Explanation_of_undefined_moments), conclude that the MGF fails to exist.

Comment: On the other hand, the characteristic function does exist and is $E\left[\exp(itX)\right]=\exp(i \theta t - |t|)$

Comment: @Henry, I am stuck on how to show that. Can you please explain more?

Comment: [This](http://wpressutexas.net/forum/attachment.php?s=9091a7bba38d09b3c631fec5de8a6cc8&attachmentid=408&d=1296667390) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846961/cauchy-distribution-characteristic-function) have some possible approaches