# What will be the pdf of $X+Y$ if $X$ and $Y$ are iid from Cauchy?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence, density-function

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ follow Cauchy distribution independent of each other. What will be the pdf of $X+Y$?

What I got by using convolution theorem is that the density $g$ of $X+Y$ is $:$

$$g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y) f(x-y)\ \mathrm {dy}$$ where $f$ is the density of the Cauchy distribution given by $f(x)=\frac {1} {\pi ({1+ x^2})},x \in \Bbb R$. Then the whole integration becomes $$\frac  {1} {\pi^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {\mathrm {dy}} {(1+y^2)(1+(x-y)^2)}.$$ Now how do I solve this integral? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know contour integration?

Comment: Yeah. I know. Is it related to contour integration?

Comment: Yes! Maybe you can try to do that, or partial fraction decomposition. The latter needs longer calculations I guess.

Comment: Yeah. I have finally found $g$ which is given by $g(x)= \frac {2} {\pi (x^2+4)},x\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: So we can say that $\frac {X+Y} {2} \sim \text {Cauchy distribution}$. Isn't it so?

Comment: Yes, you can say that!

Comment: Very interesting problem indeed!

Comment: The usual approach is to use characteristic functions. If $X$ and $Y$ are Cauchy with parameters $a$ and $b$, $$E(e^{itX})=e^{-a|t|}\qquad E(e^{itY})=e^{-b|t|}$$ If furthermore $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $$E(e^{it(X+Y)})=E(e^{itX})E(e^{itY})=e^{-a|t|}e^{-b|t|}=e^{-(a+b)|t|}$$ hence $X+Y$ is Cauchy with parameter $a+b$. Thus, it suffices to know how to prove that $$\int_\mathbb Re^{itx}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=e^{-|t|}$$ Do you?

Comment: @Did O, after having finished my answer, I saw that you already did the same in a comment

Answer (score 5):

You can try partial fraction decomposition:

\begin{align}\frac1{(1+y^2)(1+(x-y)^2)} &= \frac{x+2y}{x(x^2+4)(1+y^2)} + \frac{3x-2y}{x(x^2+4)(1+(x-y)^2)} \\
&= \frac{1}{(x^2+4)(1+y^2)}+ 
\frac{2y}{x(x^2+4)(1+y^2)} + \frac{2(x-y)}{x(x^2+4)(1+(x-y)^2)} + \frac{1}{(x^2+4)(1+(x-y)^2)}\\
&= \frac1{x^2+4}\left(\frac1{1+y^2} + \frac1{1+(x-y)^2}\right) + \frac1{x(x^2+4)}\left(\frac{y}{1+y^2} + \frac{x-y}{1+(x-y)^2}\right)
\end{align}
so we have
\begin{align}
\frac1{\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dy}{(1+y^2)(1+(x-y)^2)} &=
\frac1{\pi^2(x^2+4)}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac1{1+y^2} + \frac1{1+(x-y)^2}\right)dy + \frac1x\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{y}{1+y^2} + \frac{2(x-y)}{1+(x-y)^2}\right)dy
\right]\\
&= \frac1{\pi^2(x^2+4)}\left[\Big(\arctan(1+y^2) + \arctan(1+(x-y)^2)\Big)\Big|_{-\infty}^\infty + \frac1x\Big(\ln(1+y^2) - \ln(1+(x-y)^2)\Big)\Big|_{-\infty}^\infty
\right]\\
&= \frac1{\pi^2(x^2+4)}\left[2\pi + \frac2x \lim_{y \to \infty} \ln \left(\frac{1+y^2}{1+(x-y)^2}\right)\right]\\
&= \frac{2}{\pi(x^2+4)}
\end{align}

Comment: I have already done it. There is no need to post this unnecessary answer. Look at my comment above @mechanodroid.

Answer (score 2):

What about using characteristic functions? Let $\phi$ be the characteristic function of a Cauchy distribution. We know that
$$\phi(t) =\frac 1\pi\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{e^{itx}} {1+x^2}\, dx$$
Such integrals are many times solved on this site, for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/846961/349501), the result is
$$\phi(t) = e^{-|t|} $$
So the characteristic function of $X+Y$ is   $\phi$ squared, due to the independence of $X$ and $Y$. We conclude
$$\phi_{X+Y} (t) =\phi(t) \phi(t) =e^{-2|t|}=e^{-|2t|}$$
Indeed, we may also conclude from this that $(X+Y) /2$ is Cauchy distributed.

Comment: The process you have mentioned is somewhat related to Fourier transform. Isn't it so?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 yep. Fourier transform of the probability density. However you should be aware that the characteristic function uniquely defines the distribution of the random variable. Have you covered moment generating functions or characteristic functions? It's worth learning them since they are useful.

Comment: Yeah I covered all of them. Our professor in Indian Statistical Institute has included all these things in our first semester syllabus.