# calculate the integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-itx}}{1 + t^2} dt $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

It is possible to calculate the integral    $ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-itx}}{1 + t^2} dt
$

without using the residue theorem, nor fourier transforms

Comment: You may find it helpful. 
                                                                                                                                 https://math.stackexchange.com/a/846982/543867

Comment: I don`t know Fourier transform, nor other methods the resolution the link.

Answer (score 0):

Without Fourier transform, consider
$$\frac{e^{-itx}}{1 + t^2}=\frac{i \,e^{-itx}}2 \left(\frac{1}{ (t+i)}-\frac{1}{ (t-i)} \right)$$ making the antiderivative to be
$$\int \frac{e^{-itx}}{1 + t^2}\,dt=\frac{1}{2} i e^{-x} \text{Ei}(x(1-i t))-\frac{1}{2} i e^x \text{Ei}(-(x+i t))$$ where appears the exponential integral function.

Using the bounds and provided $x\in \mathbb{R}$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-itx}}{1 + t^2}\, dt=\pi  e^{-|x|}$$