# Are characteristic functions always differentiable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, derivatives, stochastic-calculus, characteristic-functions

I am thinking about the statement if the characteristic function of a random variable $X$, $\Phi_X$, is always differentiable.

By definition, $$\Phi_X(t)=\int_{\Bbb{R}^d}e^{i\langle t,y \rangle}P_X(dy)$$ Hence, I think it has something to do with changing the integral and the derivative right?
But my intuition tells me that there is a counterexample but I can't find one.

Comment: If $E|X| < \infty$, then $\Phi_X^\prime(t) = E(iXe^{itX})$ by LDCT, so you will have to look amongst RVs without that moment condition.

Comment: @JoseAvilez So would it work if I consider $X=1$

Comment: No. $X=1$ has finite mean.

Comment: @JoseAvilez ah sure that's because of the properties of the probability measure right? But what if I take $X=x$?

Comment: Same. All constants have finite mean.

Comment: @JoseAvilez what if I take $X\sim Exp(1)$ and define $Y=\frac{1}{X}$? Or is there a simpler one?

Comment: You may wish to take a look at Cauchy random variables as a source for counterexamples in statistics and probability. See my answer below.

Comment: @JoseAvilez the problem is that we haven't seen cauchy random variables yet, how are they defined?

Comment: @JoseAvilez you mean that this are a good class of  random variables to find counterexamples?

Comment: Again, see below for a definition. Yes, they are a good family to find counterexamples.

Comment: @JoseAvilez perfect thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $E|X| < \infty$ then the derivative of the characteristic function is given by: $$\Phi_X^\prime (t) = E(iX e^{itX})$$
as the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem would allow us to exchange the order of differentiation and integration. Thus, we must look for a random variable $X$ with infinite mean.

Let $X$ be a Cauchy random variable, so that its pdf is given by $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\pi (1 + x^2)} \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}$$
and its characteristic function [can be computed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846961/cauchy-distribution-characteristic-function) to be $$\Phi_X(t) = \exp (-|t|)$$
$\Phi_X(t)$ is readily seen not to be differentiable at $t = 0$, as desired.