# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty} ^\infty \frac{\cos(xy)}{x^2+1}dx$

Tags: integration

Is there a standard trick to compute this integral for $y\ge 0$?

$\int_{-\infty} ^\infty \frac{\cos(xy)}{x^2+1}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{y \cos(x)}{x^2+y^2}$

Hopefully the same trick could be used to evaluate

$\int_{-\infty} ^\infty \frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx$

Wolfram tells me these are both equal to $\pi e^{-y}$

Comment: the method is called residue calculation.. look up a book on complex analysis.

Comment: Your formula is only valid for $y \geq 0$. Note the integral is an even function of $y$, but $\pi{e}^{-y}$ is not. Or you could say the integral is $\pi{e}^{-|y|}$ for all $y$.

Comment: While using the residue theorem is probably the standard method, for someone who knows complex analysis, the integral can also be evaluated without complex analysis by using differentiation under the integral sign. See section 11 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf.

Comment: To use the residue theorem, is it obvious what the contour should be? I can't always find the right one.

Comment: You have to try *something*, so just go ahead and use the contours you've used in the past for integrals over the whole real line. At least try a contour before asking others what to use. This stuff is learned by experience.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. Sometimes the contour turns out to be very exotic (for example I saw one where you had to take a box with sides exactly at the half-integer marks) so I was wondering if somehow you can immediately see which one it should be.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/calculating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x1x2-mathrmdx-wit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the integral $\Re[\int_\gamma \frac{ae^{iz}}{x^2+a} dz] = \int_\gamma \Re[ \frac{ae^{iz}}{z^2+a}] dz$ where $\gamma$ is a semicircular contour of radius $R$. On the real line the contour reduces to the integral in question. We see a residue at $ia$ with a value of $2 \pi ia e^{i i a}/(2 i a) = \pi e^{-a}$ by substituting $ia$ into $\frac{ae^{iz}}{z+ia}$, which means $\Re[\int_\gamma \frac{ae^{iz}}{z^2+a} dz] = \pi e^{-a}$. Taking the limit as the countour goes to infinity yeilds the result, as the semicircular part goes to zero by Jordan's Lemma.

For the second integral, do the same argument except using $\Re[\int_\gamma \frac{-ize^{iz}}{z^2+a} dz]$

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/766005/123277). I answered the same problem without using contour integration and of course for the second integral can be evaluated using Feynman way.

Answer (score 0):

Once you evaluate the first integral then the second one can be found easily by noting that

$$ I(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(xy)}{1+x^2}dx \implies \frac{dI}{dy}=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(xy)}{1+x^2}dx  $$

which implies

> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(xy)}{1+x^2}dx = -\frac{dI}{dy}. $$

Comment: How would you justify differentiating under the integral sign?