# How to know whether to choose the x-bound or the y-bound for this triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

In my textbook for calculus 3, I have been working on example of the triple integral. Though I do know polar, cylindrical, spherical coordinates, this section of the book expects you to work with Cartesian coordinates. Anyways the problem is given as follows:

Evaluate a function $f(x, y, z) = x$, in the first octant above $z = y^{2}$ and below $z = 8 - 2x^{2} - y^{2}$.

I began by defining my $z$ bounds:

$y^{2} \leq z \leq 8 - 2x^{2} - y^{2}$.

Next, I decided that I would substitute the the lower bound of $z$ into the upper bound to find the intersection. My understanding is that once I have found this intersection, I can use it as the projection onto the $xy$ plane. I find

$x^{2} + y^{2} = 4$

I then define my $y$ bounds:

$0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{4 - x^{2}}$

This leaves my $x$ bounds as:

$0 \leq x \leq 2$

For some reason, evaluating the integral with these bounds turns out to be much more difficult than if I had sort of swapped my bounds for $x$ and $y$. My gut tells me that this is a result of the $x$ within the function being integrated, yet I cannot convince myself why (and that might be entirely wrong). I was wondering if anybody could explain the reason why the bounds I chose are less practical than the alternative. Also, I am seriously struggling with bounding equations and I was wondering if anybody had anything good I might want to read or perhaps a set of problems that builds up understanding very well. For reference, I am working out Rogawski, and my experience with this book is that just as I start to understand it a bit more, I run out of problems...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to evaluate (I think) the integral given your bounds, I suspect you just missed a simplification step somewhere, possibly involving the square root. 
\begin{align*}
\iiint f(x,y,z) \ \mathrm{d} z  \ \mathrm{d} y \ \mathrm{d} x &= \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \int^{8-2x^2-y^2}_{y^2}  x \ \ \mathrm{d} z \ \mathrm{d} y \ \mathrm{d} x 
 \\
 & = \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}   \left[ xz \right]^{z=8-2x^2-y^2}_{z=y^2} \ \ \mathrm{d} y \ \mathrm{d} x  \\
& = \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}   8x-2x^3-xy^2 - xy^2  \ \ \mathrm{d} y \ \mathrm{d} x \\
& = \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}   8x-2x^3  - 2xy^2  \ \ \mathrm{d} y \ \mathrm{d} x \\
& = \int_0^2    \left[  (8x-2x^3)y  - \frac{2}{3}xy^3 \right]^{y=\sqrt{4-x^2}}_{y=0} \ \  \mathrm{d} x \\
& = \int_0^2 2x(4-x^2)\sqrt{4-x^2}  - \frac{2}{3}x(4-x^2)^{3/2} \ \  \mathrm{d} x \\
& = \int_0^2 2x(4-x^2)^{3/2}  - \frac{2}{3}x(4-x^2)^{3/2} \ \  \mathrm{d} x \\
& = \frac{4}{3}\int_0^2 x(4-x^2)^{3/2} \ \  \mathrm{d} x \\
& = \frac{\color{blue}{2}}{3} \int_0^2 \color{blue}{2}x(4-x^2)^{3/2} \ \  \mathrm{d} x \\
& = \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{5}\left[ - (4-x^2)^{5/2} \right]^2_0 \qquad \qquad  \color{blue}{(\mbox{Note: done via substitution)}}\\
& = \frac{4}{15}\left[ 0 + 4^{5/2} \right] \\
& = \frac{4}{15} \cdot 2^5 \\
& = \frac{128}{15}
\end{align*}

But you are correct, we could attempt this integral swapping the $x$ and $y$ bounds, from $x^2+y^2=4$ we have $0\le x \le \sqrt{4-y^2}$, and $0 \le 2 \le y$. I'll do the integral again using this method.

\begin{align*}
\iiint f(x,y,z) \ \mathrm{d} z  \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y &= \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} \int^{8-2x^2-y^2}_{y^2}  x \ \ \mathrm{d} z \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y 
 \\
 & = \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}   \left[ xz \right]^{z=8-2x^2-y^2}_{z=y^2} \ \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y  \\
& = \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}   8x-2x^3-xy^2 - xy^2  \ \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y \\
& = \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}   8x-2x^3  - 2xy^2  \ \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y \\
& = \int_0^2 \left[ 4x^2-\frac{1}{2}x^4  - x^2y^2\right]^{x=\sqrt{4-y^2}}_{x=0}  \ \ \mathrm{d} y \\
& = \int_0^2 4(4-y^2) -\frac{1}{2}(4-y^2)^2 -(4-y^2)y^2 \ \ \mathrm{d} y \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^2  16 - 8 y^2 + y^4 \ \ \mathrm{d} y  \qquad \qquad \color{grey}{\mbox{(done in W|A)}} \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\left[16y - \frac{8}{3}y^3 + \frac{1}{5}y^5\right]^2_0 \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\left(16(2) - \frac{8}{3}(2)^3 + \frac{1}{5}\cdot 2^5 \right) \\
& = \frac{128}{5}
\end{align*}

Now, this second method leaves you just with a polynomial to integrate rather than a substitution integral, but I'd say they are roughly equivalent in difficulty. Sometimes you simply *can't* integrate a given function using a particular order, and must swap. For example, integrating the function $f(x,y) = \exp(x^2)$ over the triangle in the first quadrant bounded by the $x$-axis, $y=x$ and $x=1$, is simply impossible using the order 
$$
\iint f(x,y) \ \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y = \int_{y=0}^{y=1} \int_{x=y}^{x=1} \mathrm{e}^{x^2} \ \ \mathrm{d} x \ \mathrm{d} y,
$$
as you probably know. However if we swap the order, 
$$
\iint f(x,y) \ \ \mathrm{d} y \ \mathrm{d} x = \int_{x=0}^{x=1} \int_{y=0}^{y=x} \mathrm{e}^{x^2} \ \ \mathrm{d} y \ \mathrm{d} x,
$$
we obtain
$$
\iint f(x,y) \ \ \mathrm{d} y \ \mathrm{d} x = \int_{0}^{1} x\mathrm{e}^{x^2}   \ \mathrm{d} x,
$$
which is a simple substitution integral.

Final advice would be to keep practising, remember your substitution technique from your earlier studies, and maybe have a look at [these](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DIGeneralRegion.aspx) notes and practise some double integrals where you swap the order - I always find this guy's site helpful for practise problems.

Comment: If you'd like a tricky problem afterwards to test your skills, I wrote one here that's quite challenging - 

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/772119/78722